# Ubuntu Unity desktop 20.04 launcher item handling broke after last update

Tags: unity

The Ubuntu Unity desktop on 20.04 launcher item handling got broken with latest update. The programs are grouped to same group now always and under only one item in launcher, when earlier it had different profile Firefox instances grouped independently in the launcher, for.ex. I had 2 profiles for Firefox and they had their own item (icon/symbol) in the launcher, but this is not the case anymore after latest update.

Why did this change? Launcher is not usable anymore.

Please fix it back the way it was earlier.

Comment: Hello. Can you please try and re word the question? As currently written I do not understand what you are saying. Also the last line sounds like a threat, not a good way to ask for help.

Comment: Umm … very few of the Unity development team frequent AskUbuntu. Asking a bunch of volunteer question-answerers to return your system to a previous behaviour is outside of this site’s scope 

Comment: The community volunteers who maintain Unity would be interested to know about your issue. You should tell them. AskUbuntu is the wrong place to reach them; they don't hang out here. Several of them do hang out at discourse.ubuntu.com

Comment: I did reword it. Should be easy to understand.

XFCE Ubuntu + Firefox same version dont have this issue. So this IS AN BUG IN THE UNITY. PLEASE FIX!